# how to convert to an Excel file to xml file by uploading it using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create a page with an Upload control. When I Upload an excel file
it should read the content of Excel file to Xml COding Conversion

Comment: Have you written the code that converts an excel file to XML?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).